# Hiding Script Host error when network path not found

Tags: group-policy, logon-scripts

I have a Group Policy logon script that is located at and runs from the NETLOGON share.

When a user is off domain and logs on, an error is displayed that the path is not found.

This frightens and alarms our user base and I need to hide the error.

Is there a way to prevent the Script Host error and if not found, don't run the script?

Comment: What type of script?

Comment: a VBS script. Used for standardizing user's outlook signatures.

Comment: I don't know a proper fix. Can you test with Group Policy Caching disabled? https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.GroupPolicy::EnableLogonOptimization